# Find object inside collection of List

Tags: c#, linq

I have five strong-typed `List` objects. Every object inside every `List` have property `Rating` and `Vote`.

How can I select only 10 top rated  object from all `List`'s objects? if `Rating` equal then need use `Vote`

Example(select 2 top rated):

`List<Film>`:

```
0 element: rating = 1, vote = 2;  
1 element: rating = 4, vote = 5;
```

`List<Clubs>`:

```
0 element: rating  = 5, vote = 3;  
1 element: rating = 4, vote = 3;
```

Result: 0 element from `Clubs` and 1 element from `Film`

Comment: Are `Rating` and `Vote` properties of an interface that `Film` and `Club` share? If not, you're stuck with reflection or (with C# 4.0 onwards) `dynamic`.

Comment: How do you define the "rating" in terms of `Rating` and `Vote` properties? In other words, what's the *ordering* of items by these two criteria?

Comment: first by Rating, if Rating is equal then compare Vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If there is no common sub-class among these element types**, you can use LINQ to project the lists using a generic `Tuple<int, int, object>` (i.e. rating, vote, and the original element instance) containing the two properties you are interested in.  Then you can do a simple query to pick the top 10 elements:

```
List<A> ax = /* ... */;
List<B> bx = /* ... */;
List<C> cx = /* ... */;
/* ... */

IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, object>> ratingsAndVotes =
    ax.Select((a) => Tuple.Create(a.Rating, a.Vote, a)).Concat(
    bx.Select((b) => Tuple.Create(b.Rating, b.Vote, b)).Concat(
    cx.Select((c) => Tuple.Create(c.Rating, c.Vote, c)) /* ... */;
Tuple<int, int, object>[] topTenItems = 
    ratingsAndVotes.OrderByDescending((i) => i.Item1).ThenByDescending((i) => i.Item2).Take(10).ToArray();
// topTenItems now contains the top 10 items out of all the lists;
// for each tuple element, Item1 = rating, Item2 = vote,
// Item3 = original list item (as object)
```

Answer (score 8):

Try something like below

var topTen = yourList.OrderBy(x => x.Rating).ThenBy(z => z.Vote).Take(10)

Comment: Linq is the way to go :) and if list is big or time consuming you can do that in parallel as well :)

Comment: it's only for one collection. Need take from 5.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with something like:

```
  var res = l1.Concat(l2).Concat(l3).Concat(l4).Concat(l5)
                    .OrderByDescending(k => k.Rating)
                    .ThenBy(k=>k.Vote)
                    .Take(10).ToList();
```

where l1...l5 are your lists

Answer (score 1):

You can use OrderBy and ThenBy to order by two (or more) fields and then use Take to get the top 10:

```
var myList = new List<Film>();
// ... populate list with some stuff
var top10 = myList.OrderBy(f => f.Rating).ThenBy(f => f.Vote).Take(10);
```

Hope that helps :)